# Checking Maven Version

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, jar

I have just installed maven.
I downloaded distributive, extracted files and set bin value environment variables, but when I type `mvn -version`  in CMD I am getting message:

> 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
>   operable program or batch file.

I am writing project. I have one project DatabaseAPI where I have logic of database and POJO classes. second project is CoreAPI where I have some methods. For DatabaseAPI I make a jar file using eclipse (export -> jar). In core I add external jar (DatabaseAPI.jar). For CoreAPI I make a jar file using eclipse (export -> jar). In core I add external jar (CoreAPI.jar) and I tried to start tomcat (I have servlets in my project and swing too). I got error during starting and error is `ClassNotFoundException` (One of the classes in CoreAPI did not find). Is it problem of exporting using Eclipse ?

Comment: At the time of installing maven , i downloaded it from http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi    where the latest version was 3.3.3 .
However, typing  `mvn -version` shows `version: "3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64"`
What is my actual version?

Answer (score 86):

**Shorter**

```
mvn -v
```

or

```
mvn --version
```

Output:

> ```
> Apache Maven 3.0.5 (...)
> Maven home: ...
> Java version: 1.8.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation
> Java home: ...
> Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
> OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
> ```

The other command (`mvn -version`) works because it starts with `mvn -v`. 

You can also try `mvn -v123` and you'll get the same output.

**Details**:

```
mvn -h
```

or

```
mvn --help
```

Output:

> ```
> ...
> -V,--show-version                      Display version information
>                                        WITHOUT stopping build
> -v,--version                           Display version information
> ```

**Command is not recognized**

Probably you are in one of the following 2 situations:

1. You didn't add the Maven to the `Path` 
    (run `ECHO.%PATH:;= & ECHO.%` in cmd to see if you are in this situation).

   - go to Control Panel\User Accounts\User Accounts 
      (or click on your photo from the start menu)
   - click **Change my environment variables**
   - click on **New...** and add:

     - `M2_HOME=<your_path>`
     - `MAVEN_HOME=%M2_HOME%`
     - `MAVEN_BIN=%M2_HOME%\bin`
   - click on **Edit...** and add the `;%MAVEN_BIN%` at the end of the `Path`
2. You added it to the `Path`, but you didn't open a new command prompt.

   - open a new command prompt, because the environment variables are not updated automatically

Comment: Thanks! this was helpful I did not know that mvn -V and mvn -v did different things

Comment: When I type mvn --version or mvn -v, I get the version of everything but maven! Here's what I get:

Maven home: /custom/apache-maven
Java version: 9.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way?

Comment: @MiguelMunoz , can you check the values of the following environment variables `M2_HOME` & `PATH`?

Answer (score 17):

Type the command `mvn -version` directly in your maven directory, you probably haven't added it to your PATH. [Here are](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/)  explained details of how to add maven to your PATH variable (I guess you use Windows because you are talking about CMD).

Answer (score 7):

Step 1: 
    Start button -> Computer menu item -> Properties on right click menu item -> Advanced System Settings button on left panel -> Advanced tab in System Properties dialog -> Environment Variables button -> System variables table

Step 2:
   Add MAVEN_HOME variable

[image]

Step 3: 
    Update PATH variable
[image]

Step 4: 
   Make sure you have JAVA_HOME variable correctly
[image]

step 5: open console and check below command

mvn -v

Answer (score 2):

You need to add path to *svn.exe* file to system environment, variable *PATH*, after that you can run command *mvn* from any folder. You can do it from command line(cmd.exe) like this, for example:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\maven\bin
```

Or you can got to the folder where *mvn.exe* is, and run your command there.

And you need not `mvn -version`, but `mvn --version` parameter.

Comment: I make it. I set PATH

Comment: Can you help me solving second problem ? ClassNotFoundException ?

Comment: @Chala Yes, but you need to create another question about it.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows machine open command line terminal :

```
> mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.8.3 (ff8e977a158738155dc465c6a97ffaf31982d739)
Maven home: C:\Users\ajayk\OneDrive\Documents\apache-maven-3.8.3
Java version: 11.0.12, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: 
"windows"
```

[3 ways to run Spring Boot apps from command line - Java Brains](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Le5YjYNYtZg)

[How to install Apache Maven on Windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=km3tLti4TCM)

Answer (score 1):

On terminal type `mvn -v` and the output will look like the image shown below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt go inside the maven folder and execute mvn -version, it will show you maven vesrion al

Answer (score 0):

you can use just

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version></version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

i faced with similar issue when i first installed it. It worked when i added user variable name- PATH and 
variable value- C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin

variable value should direct to "bin" folder. finally check with cmd (mvn -v) in a new cmd prompt. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

On terminal type mvn --version  or mvn -v and check its work !

```
mvn --version
mvn -v
```